# edかexで<CR+LF>を<LF>に変換するバッチ編集は可能でしょうか

Tags: shellscript

チームでプログラムしていると時々、ファイルの文字コードや改行コードを乱してしまう人がいます。私のチームでは`ruby on rails`を使った開発をしていて、ホストサーバーを`CentOS`と定めているため、最初から文字コードを`UTF-8`、改行コードを`LF`のみと定めています。

間違いの大半は`windows`で編集したファイルの改行コードが`CR`+`LF`に変換保存されてしまうことで起きています。それ自体は仕方ないのですが、何度も手で直すのが苦痛になってきました。
`vi`で直すにはファイルをいちいち開かねばならず（しかも`vi`にそれほど詳しくもなく）、`sed`や`tr`コマンドを使うことも考えましたが、一旦オリジナルのファイルをどこかに退避させないと、元のファイルを上書きできません。

それで、`ed`や`ex`を使うスクリプトを作ればバッチでファイルの直接編集・保存ができるので上手くやれるんじゃないかと思いついた次第です。
ですが制御文字を`ed`/`ex`で書き換えるサンプルを手早く見つけることができず、もしご存知の方がいらしたら教えていただけるとありがたいです。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

edやexである必要はありません。

sed の `-i` オプションを使えば、in-placeで(オリジナルを退避させずに)置き換えができます。
そのため以下のようなコマンドで、改行コードの変更ができるでしょう。

```
sed -i -e 's/\r$//' [INPUT_FILES]...
```

ただしCygwinやMinGWでは設定によっては上手くできない場合があることには注意してください。

Comment: sedでできたのですね。しかもsedなので、この答えでそのままed/exの編集記法に応用できることを思い出しました。

Answer (score 4):

オイラならソースコード管理ツールで吸収しちゃうかな・・・

[git](/questions/tagged/git) なら `core.autocrlf`
[mercurial](/questions/tagged/mercurial) ならエクステンション `eol`

Answer (score 2):

`nkf -w -d --overwrite`

Comment: sed は標準で入っているので、sed の方がよいと思います。
nkf --overwrite の利点はタイムスタンプが変わらないことです。

Answer (score 2):

dos2unix コマンド使いましょう。引数にファイルを渡せばファイルに直接上書きします。`-k`オプションでタイムスタンプも維持します。

```
$ dos2unix -k file.txt
```

カレントディレクトリ以下のファイルを修正する場合はfindからxargsに繋げばOKです。

```
$ find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 dos2unix -k
```

sed 等のストリームエディタを直接使うのはおすすめしません。バイナリファイルを壊してしまいます。
windowsユーザの過ちが改行コードだけなら(文字コードはきちんとBOM無しUTF-8で保存しているなら)、dos2unixでほとんど事足ります。

Comment: バイナリファイルを壊す！その視点はなかったです……参考になりました。

Answer (score 1):

別ファイルは作りたくないのかもしれませんが、下の別ファイルを作ってmvするというのは良くやる手です。

```
for F in *; do tr -d \\r < $F > $F+ && mv $F+ $F; done
```